# Pandas: How to grab unique values from a group?

Tags: pandas, group-by, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame `df1` with columns `A, B, C`, where `C` is integers. I want to group by `df1.A` and grab the top 5 rows of each group based on `df1.C`. However, I want to grab the top 5 values based on `df1.C` BUT with unique `df1.B` values. So the 5 rows grabbed should all have different `df1.B` values.

What I have so far grabs me what I want, except the `df1.B` values are not unique. How can I rewrite this so that the 5 rows contain unique column `B` for each group?

```
df2 = df1.sort('C').groupby('A').tail(5)
```

Sample data:

```
      A          B               C   
1 'group1'     'apple'           3       
2 'group1'     'apple'           2
3 'group2'     'apple'           1
4 'group1'     'orange'          2
5 'group3'     'pineapple'       3  
  ...
```

The output 5 rows for the `df1.A == 'group1'` should NOT include both 1 and 2. It should only include one of the two.

Comment: You could just set the index on A and B no?

Comment: Do I do that after I perform the groupby?

Comment: You can either groupby both A and B and then get the top 5 values, or set the index on A and B, and then get the top 5 values for C